# Ag-grid - Setting hierarchy and total in Angular 7

Tags: c#, angular, ag-grid

I am binding data to ag-grid in angular 7 application and having problem creating hiearchy. I currently need to display list grouped by strategies and Funds. Please do let me know if I am doing it right. I am looking at achieving the following format. There should be a space after each grouping for clarity of data. I am looking at achieving as seen in the screenshot below.  As seen in the screenshot Manager Strategy and Fund could repeat. The space between the two strategies is used to display the total.

Emv would contain the sum of Emv field and Percent would contain the total of GroupPercent field

[image]

ViewModel

```
  public class FirmWideAllocationsViewModel
    {
        public List<string> Hierarchy
        { get; set; }
        private decimal _groupPercent;
        public int FirmID { get; set; }
        public string FirmName { get; set; }
        public int? ManagerStrategyID { get; set; }
        public int? ManagerFundID { get; set; }
        public int ManagerAccountClassID{ get; set; }
        public int? ManagerFundOrClassID { get; set; }
        public string ManagerFundName { get; set; }
        public string ManagerAccountingClassName { get; set; }
        public string ManagerStrategyName { get; set; }
        public int? ProductID { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public int? Quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal? Nav { get; set; }
        public DateTime EvalDate { get; set; }
        public int? DefaultStrategyID { get; set; }
        public string DEFAULT_STRATEGY_NAME { get; set; }
        public decimal Usd_Emv { get; set; }
        //needed for kendo aggregates
        public decimal UsdEmv => Usd_Emv;
        public decimal Emv { get; set; }
        public decimal Weight { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public decimal Percent { get; set; } // manual calc
        [NotMapped]
        public decimal Sort
        {
            get
            {
                return ProductName == "Other"
                    ? decimal.MaxValue
                    : Usd_Emv;
            }
        }
        [NotMapped]
        public decimal GroupPercent
        {
            get { return _groupPercent; }
            set { _groupPercent = value; }
        }

    }
```

Controller

```
public class AllocationsController : ApiControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Allocations/{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Details(int id, DateTime date)
    {

        var viewModel = GetAllocationsViewModel(id, date);
        if (viewModel == null) return NotFound(); 
        return Ok(viewModel);
    }


      private AllocationsViewModel GetAllocationsViewModel(int id, DateTime date)
    {

        var ms = GetStrategy(id);

        DateTime d = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
        if (ms.FIRM_ID != null)
        {

            var allocationsGrouped = Mapper.Map<List<FIRMWIDE_MANAGER_ALLOCATION>, List<FirmWideAllocationsViewModel>>(GetAllocationsGrouped(EntityType.Firm, firm.ID, d).ToList());
            foreach (var ag in allocationsGrouped)
            {
                ag.Hierarchy = new List<string>
                {ag.ManagerStrategyName, ag.ManagerFundName};
            }


            var vm = new AllocationsViewModel
            {
                ManagerAllocations = allocationsGrouped
            };

            return vm;
        }

        }
```

Ag-grid column definition

```
setGridOptions() {
        this.GridOptions = {
            columnDefs: this.getColumns(),
            rowData: this.AllocationDetails,
            enableFilter: true,
            treeData: true,
            enableColResize: true,
            animateRows: true,
            groupDefaultExpanded: 1,
            enableSorting: true,
            suppressCellSelection: true,
            getDataPath: function (data) {
                return data.Hierarchy;
            },
            onGridReady: e => {
                if (!e || !e.api) {
                    return;
                }
                e.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
                this.setDefaultSortOrder();
            },
            getRowStyle: (params) => {
                if (params.node.level === 0) {
                    return { 'background-color': '#FCE7D7' };
                }
            },

            autoGroupColumnDef: {

                headerName: 'Manager Strategy', width: 300
            },
        };
    }


    private getColumns(): Array<any> {
        const self = this;
        const definition = [
            { headerName: 'Date', field: 'EvalDate', hide: true },
            { headerName: 'Firm ID', field: 'FirmID', hide: true },
            { headerName: 'Manager Strategy ID', field: 'FirmName', hide: true },
            { headerName: 'Firm', field: 'ManagerStrategyID', hide: true },
            { headerName: 'Manager Strategy', field: 'ManagerStrategyName' },
            { headerName: 'Fund ID', field: 'ManagerFundID', hide: true },
            { headerName: 'Fund', field: 'ManagerFundName' },
            { headerName: 'Portfolio', field: 'ProductName' },
            { headerName: 'As Of', field: 'EvalDate',   cellRenderer: (data) => {
                return data.value ? (new Date(data.value)).toLocaleDateString() : '';
             } },
            { headerName: 'EMV (USD)', field: 'UsdEmv',  valueFormatter: currencyFormatter },
            { headerName: 'Percent', field: 'GroupPercent' },

        ];
```

UI

```
  <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div *ngIf="AllocationDetails && AllocationDetails.ManagerAllocations" class="panel-body" style="width:100%">
                <div [style.height.px]="GridHeight()" [style.width.%]="100" style="float: left;">
                        <ag-grid-angular #agGrid class="ag-theme-balham" [gridOptions]="GridOptions" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"
                            [columnDefs]="ColumnDefs" [rowData]="AllocationDetails.ManagerAllocations"  rowHeight="30" headerHeight="30" rowSelection="single">
                        </ag-grid-angular>
                    </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

JSON

```
[[{"ProductId":2844,"ProductName":"*DO NOT USE* City Plan LLC","ProductType":"Strategic Partnerships"},{"ProductId":2840,"ProductName":"*DO NOT USE* Baha'i Separate Managed Account","ProductType":"Strategic Partnerships"},{"ProductId":2851,"ProductName":"Test Special Opportunities Evergreen Fund Ltd.","ProductType":"Strategic Partnerships"},{"ProductId":2852,"ProductName":"Test Spafid Multi-Strategy Fund","ProductType":"Strategic Partnerships"}],[{"ProductId":2745,"ProductName":"Test Special Opportunities Fund III Master LP","ProductType":"Commingled Fund"},{"ProductId":2854,"ProductName":"Test Select Opportunities II Ltd.","ProductType":"Commingled Fund"},{"ProductId":2746,"ProductName":"Test Structured Income Fund I Ltd.","ProductType":"Commingled Fund"},{"ProductId":2749,"ProductName":"Test Structured Income Fund II Ltd.","ProductType":"Commingled Fund"},{"ProductId":2778,"ProductName":"Test Structured Income Fund II-A Ltd.","ProductType":"Commingled Fund"},{"ProductId":2794,"ProductName":"Test Hedge Fund Opportunities II Ltd. Continuing","ProductType":"Commingled Fund"}],[{"ProductId":2828,"ProductName":"ICBC Quantitative HengSheng Choice Pooled Fund.","ProductType":"Sub-Advisory "},{"ProductId":2853,"ProductName":"HEC SPV II Cayman LP","ProductType":"Sub-Advisory "},{"ProductId":2800,"ProductName":"TP ETP Offshore LP","ProductType":"Sub-Advisory "},{"ProductId":2829,"ProductName":"ICBC Quantitative Xincheng Choice Pooled Fund Trust.","ProductType":"Sub-Advisory "},{"ProductId":1841,"ProductName":"Brightgate Absolute Return FIL","ProductType":"Sub-Advisory "}],[{"ProductId":2827,"ProductName":"Test Alternative Income Strategy.","ProductType":"Liquid Alternatives"},{"ProductId":1603,"ProductName":"Test Alternative Core Fund","ProductType":"Liquid Alternatives"}]]
```

Comment: sorry but it's unclear what structure you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The structure should be such that it should be grouped by Strategy Name and Fundname. Say for example Strategy ABC currently has Strategy ABC repeated. Same is the case for FundName. So ideally , there should be only Strategy ABC under the Manager Strategy column. Similary there would be several Fundnames with repeating ones as well for a specific stragegy. Hence it could FundName1 twice or thrice and Fundname2 twice or thrice. Each one should be grouped for that strategy.

Comment: could you show a sample in JSON format?

Comment: I have updated the post with the json format